# Strange plus sign in the Lie derivative of a 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

While the coordinate expression for the Lie derivative of a vector field $Y$ with respect to another vector field $X$ is given by

$$
L_X Y = \sum_j \left\{X^j\left( \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}\right)
        -  Y^j \left(\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\right)\right\}
$$

there is a plus sign in the coordinate expression for the Lie derivative of a 1-form $\alpha$ with respect to $X$

$$
L_X \alpha = \sum_j \left\{X^j\left( \frac{\partial a^i}{\partial x^j}\right)
        +  a^j \left(\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\right)\right\}dx_i
$$

The $a^i$ and $a^j$ are the coordinates of the 1-form.

Where does this plus sign come from?

Comment: The second term in the second line should read $a^j \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_i}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\alpha,Y) = \sum_j \alpha_j Y^j$ denote the contraction of a $1$-form $\alpha = \sum_j \alpha_j dx^j$ with a vector field $Y = \sum_j X^j \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. The Lie derivative $L_X\alpha$ of a $1$-form $\alpha$ with respect to a vector field $X$ is defined precisely so that for any other vector field $Y$, we have the following Leibniz rule
$$
 X(\alpha,Y) = (L_X\alpha,Y) + (\alpha,L_XY).
$$
But now,
$$
 X(\alpha,Y) = \left(\sum_i X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right)\left(\sum_j \alpha_j Y^j\right) = \sum_i X^i \sum_j\left(\frac{\partial \alpha_j}{\partial x^i} Y^j + \alpha_j \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i} \right)\\ = \sum_j \left(\sum_i X^i \frac{\partial \alpha_j}{\partial x^i}\right)Y^j + \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i},
$$
whilst
$$
 (\alpha,L_X Y) = \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i \left(X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}-Y^i\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\right) = \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i} - \sum_j \left(\sum_i \alpha_i \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j} \right) Y^j,
$$
so that
$$
 (L_X\alpha,Y) = X(\alpha,Y) - (\alpha,L_X Y)\\
= \sum_j \left(\sum_i X^i \frac{\partial \alpha_j}{\partial x^i}\right)Y^j + \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i} - \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i} + \sum_j \left(\sum_i \alpha_i \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j} \right) Y^j\\
= \sum_j \left(\sum_i \left(X^i \frac{\partial \alpha_j}{\partial x^i} + \alpha_i \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\right) \right) Y^j.
$$
Since this is true for arbitrary vector fields $Y$, it therefore follows that
$$
 L_X \alpha = \sum_j \left(\sum_i \left(X^i \frac{\partial \alpha_j}{\partial x^i} + \alpha_i \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\right) \right) dx^j
$$
with the plus sign you were wondering about, which is forced upon you precisely by that Leibniz rule above.

Comment: Many thanks for these very nice and detailled explanatins !